# Change Video src with an add function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have following click function:

```
$('.videos').click(function (event) {
    var myElem = $(this).attr('id');
   
    document.getElementById('video').innerHTML = '<video autoplay muted loop id="video"><source src="site/image/videos/'+ myElem +'.mp4"></video>';
    document.getElementById('video').play();
});
```

to change the src of my background video, It works fine but now I need to configure the `src` with 2 control sections. For example myElem could get this `IDs`: `lorem`, `ipsum`, `dolor`, `sit`

The second section to edit the video src will have IDs like this: `first`, `second`, `third`
So that I could get a string like this in the src in the end: `site/image/videos/lorem_first.mp4` or `site/image/videos/ipsum_third.mp4` and so on...
Now I could make another click function but if I would do that with innerHTML, I would replace the whole Element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to work directly on the `src` attribute of the video element instead of editing the whole `innerHTML` string and replacing it every time.

```js
let mySrc = '';

// your logic ...

document.getElementById('video').src = mySrc;
```

Comment: and how do you imagine the logic to be like ? I mean when you have 2 config sections you need to somehow build it like that it fires the function first when the second configuration is made. so if I have for example 2 button rows with 4 buttons each, I would need to somehow build it like that it only fires the function into my string when I chose a option on both config sections.

Comment: I would do the following: when I click a button from Nth row I would set a variable that stores the clicked option for each row. Also, every time I click a button I check if both variables have been set: if true I would set the new video src. It would be easier if you use checkboxes instead of buttons.

Comment: thank you, your hint solved my problem now.